# Server 2012 and RDP Properties

Tags: security, windows-server-2012, rdp, remote-desktop-services

I am looking to change RDP-Tcp-Properties security layer to: 'RDP security layer' in **Windows Server 2012**.

Looked up: [Windows 2012 R2 - RDP properties?](https://serverfault.com/questions/661748/windows-2012-r2-rdp-properties)

However this server has no RD features/roles installed and is not a part of a domain.

Any idea of how to do so? Maybe through PowerShell?

I have made the change via GPO, however when opening RDP to this server, the selection of users/local/ldap does not show. is it possible to do so at all in 2012? (ldap Auth& Pgina)

[PS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr405.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to change it in local policies under:

**`Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Security.`**

You can invoke the console via `CMD > gpedit.msc`.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I have made the change via GPO, however when opening RDP to this server, the selection of users/local/ldap does not show.  is it possible to do so at all in 2012? (ldap Auth& Pgina)

Comment: Can u post the screenshot of this selection in your question?

Comment: In 2008 R2 when changing the option shown in the screenshot, there is a selection on login methods once the RDP session starts. That allows the use of LDAP (with pGina). Any ideas?

Comment: any other ideas?